# Serializing a Many to Many Relationship w/ Peewee and Marshmallow

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee, marshmallow

I have a PostgreSQL database with a many-to-many users to tags relationship with the following tables:

- *social_user:* user information
- *tag:* tag information
- *user_tag:* many-to-many relationship between *social_user* and *tag*

I am attempting to build out a simple API to access data in this database using Flask, Peewee, and Marshmallow. We can ignore Flask for now, but I am trying to create a schema for *social_user* that will allow me to dump in a query that returns a user or users with their respective tags. I am looking for a response that looks something like the following:

> ```
> {
>     "id": "[ID]",
>     "handle": "[HANDLE]",
>     "local_id": "[LOCAL_ID]",
>     "platform_slug": "[PLATFORM_SLUG]",
>     "tags": [
>         {
>             "id": "[ID]",
>             "title": "[TITLE]",
>             "tag_type": "[TAG_TYPE]"
>         },
>         {
>             "id": "[ID]",
>             "title": "[TITLE]",
>             "tag_type": "[TAG_TYPE]"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

I've managed to do this by including a second query that pulls the tags in the *social_user* schema in a @post_dump wrapped function, however, this feels like a hack and also seems like it would be slow with a large number of users (UPDATE: this is VERY slow, I tested it on 369 users). I imagine there is something I can do with Marshmallow's [`fields.Nested` field type](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nesting.html). Is there a better way to serialize this relationship with only one Peewee query? My code is below:

```
# just so you are aware of my namespaces
import marshmallow as marsh
import peewee as pw
```

### Peewee Models

```
db = postgres_ext.PostgresqlExtDatabase(
    register_hstore = False,
    **json.load(open('postgres.json'))
)

class Base_Model(pw.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Tag(Base_Model):
    title = pw.CharField()
    tag_type = pw.CharField(db_column = 'type')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tag'

class Social_User(Base_Model):
    handle = pw.CharField(null = True)
    local_id = pw.CharField()
    platform_slug = pw.CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'social_user'

class User_Tag(Base_Model):
    social_user_id = pw.ForeignKeyField(Social_User)
    tag_id = pw.ForeignKeyField(Tag)

    class Meta:
        primary_key = pw.CompositeKey('social_user_id', 'tag_id')
        db_table = 'user_tag'
```

### Marshmallow Schemas

```
class Tag_Schema(marsh.Schema):
    id = marsh.fields.Int(dump_only = True)
    title = marsh.fields.Str(required = True)
    tag_type = marsh.fields.Str(required = True, default = 'descriptive')

class Social_User_Schema(marsh.Schema):
    id = marsh.fields.Int(dump_only = True)
    local_id = marsh.fields.Str(required = True)
    handle = marsh.fields.Str()
    platform_slug = marsh.fields.Str(required = True)
    tags = marsh.fields.Nested(Tag_Schema, many = True, dump_only = True)

    def _get_tags(self, user_id):
        query = Tag.select().join(User_Tag).where(User_Tag.social_user_id == user_id)
        tags, errors = tags_schema.dump(query)
        return tags

    @marsh.post_dump(pass_many = True)
    def post_dump(self, data, many):
        if many:
            for datum in data:
                datum['tags'] = self._get_tags(datum['id']) if datum['id'] else []
        else:
            data['tags'] = self._get_tags(data['id'])
        return data

user_schema = Social_User_Schema()
users_schema = Social_User_Schema(many = True)
tags_schema = Tag_Schema(many = True)
```

Here are some tests to demonstrate the functionality:

```
db.connect()
query = Social_User.get(Social_User.id == 825)
result, errors = user_schema.dump(query)
db.close()
pprint(result)
```

> ```
> {'handle': 'test',
>  'id': 825,
>  'local_id': 'test',
>  'platform_slug': 'tw',
>  'tags': [{'id': 20, 'tag_type': 'descriptive', 'title': 'this'},
>           {'id': 21, 'tag_type': 'descriptive', 'title': 'that'}]}
> ```

```
db.connect()
query = Social_User.select().where(Social_User.platform_slug == 'tw')
result, errors = users_schema.dump(query)
db.close()
pprint(result)
```

> ```
> [{'handle': 'test',
>   'id': 825,
>   'local_id': 'test',
>   'platform_slug': 'tw',
>   'tags': [{'id': 20, 'tag_type': 'descriptive', 'title': 'this'},
>            {'id': 21, 'tag_type': 'descriptive', 'title': 'that'}]},
>  {'handle': 'test2',
>   'id': 826,
>   'local_id': 'test2',
>   'platform_slug': 'tw',
>   'tags': []}]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this can be done using the [`ManyToMany` field](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#ManyToManyField) in the Peewee models and manually setting the `through_model`. The `ManyToMany` field allows you to add a field to your models that relates two tables to one another, typically it automatically creates the relationship table (`through_model`) itself, but you can set it manually.

I am working with the [3.0 alpha of Peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/tree/3.0a), but I'm sure many people are working with the current stable release so I'll include both versions. We'll use a `DeferredThroughModel` object and the `ManyToMany` field, in Peewee 2.x these are in the "playhouse" in 3.x they're part of the main Peewee release. We'll also remove the `@post_dump` wrapped function:

### Peewee Models

```
# Peewee 2.x
# from playhouse import fields
# User_Tag_Proxy = fields.DeferredThroughModel()

# Peewee 3.x
User_Tag_Proxy = pw.DeferredThroughModel()

class Tag(Base_Model):
    title = pw.CharField()
    tag_type = pw.CharField(db_column = 'type')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tag'

class Social_User(Base_Model):
    handle = pw.CharField(null = True)
    local_id = pw.CharField()
    platform_slug = pw.CharField()
    # Peewee 2.x
    # tags = fields.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name = 'users', through_model = User_Tag_Proxy)

    # Peewee 3.x
    tags = pw.ManyToManyField(Tag, backref = 'users', through_model = User_Tag_Proxy)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'social_user'

class User_Tag(Base_Model):
    social_user = pw.ForeignKeyField(Social_User, db_column = 'social_user_id')
    tag = pw.ForeignKeyField(Tag, db_column = 'tag_id')

    class Meta:
        primary_key = pw.CompositeKey('social_user', 'tag')
        db_table = 'user_tag'

User_Tag_Proxy.set_model(User_Tag)
```

### Marshmallow Schemas

```
class Social_User_Schema(marsh.Schema):
    id = marsh.fields.Int(dump_only = True)
    local_id = marsh.fields.Str(required = True)
    handle = marsh.fields.Str()
    platform_slug = marsh.fields.Str(required = True)
    tags = marsh.fields.Nested(Tag_Schema, many = True, dump_only = True)

user_schema = Social_User_Schema()
users_schema = Social_User_Schema(many = True)
```

In practice it works exactly the same as using a `@post_dump` wrapped function. Unfortunately, while this appears to be the "right" way to approach this problem, it is actually slightly slower.

### --UPDATE--

I've managed to accomplish the same thing in 1/100th of the time. It's a bit of a hack and could use some cleaning up but it works! Instead of making changes to the models I've instead adjusted how I gather and process the data before passing it to the schema to serialize.

### Peewee Models

```
class Tag(Base_Model):
    title = pw.CharField()
    tag_type = pw.CharField(db_column = 'type')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tag'

class Social_User(Base_Model):
    handle = pw.CharField(null = True)
    local_id = pw.CharField()
    platform_slug = pw.CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'social_user'

class User_Tag(Base_Model):
    social_user = pw.ForeignKeyField(Social_User, db_column = 'social_user_id')
    tag = pw.ForeignKeyField(Tag, db_column = 'tag_id')

    class Meta:
        primary_key = pw.CompositeKey('social_user', 'tag')
        db_table = 'user_tag'
```

### Marshmallow Schema

```
class Social_User_Schema(marsh.Schema):
    id = marsh.fields.Int(dump_only = True)
    local_id = marsh.fields.Str(required = True)
    handle = marsh.fields.Str()
    platform_slug = marsh.fields.Str(required = True)
    tags = marsh.fields.Nested(Tag_Schema, many = True, dump_only = True)

user_schema = Social_User_Schema()
users_schema = Social_User_Schema(many = True)
```

### Query

For the new query we'll be joining (`LEFT_OUTER`) the three tables (*Social_User*, *Tag*, and *User_Tag*) with *Social_User* as our source of truth. We want to make sure we get every user whether they have tags or not. This will return users multiple times depending on the number of tags they have, so we'll need to reduce this by iterating over each and using a dictionary to store the objects. In each of these new `Social_User` objects will add a `tags` list to which we'll append the `Tag` objects.

```
db.connect()
query = (Social_User.select(User_Tag, Social_User, Tag)
    .join(User_Tag, pw.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER)
    .join(Tag, pw.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER)
    .order_by(Social_User.id))

users = {}
last = None
for result in query:
    user_id = result.id
    if (user_id not in users):
        # creates a new Social_User object matching the user data
        users[user_id] = Social_User(**result.__data__)
        users[user_id].tags = []
    try:
        # extracts the associated tag
        users[user_id].tags.append(result.user_tag.tag)
    except AttributeError:
        pass

result, errors = users_schema.dump(users.values())
db.close()
pprint(result)
```

Comment: Great job! It is really helpful. I used this library instead of creating the schema from scratch. https://github.com/klen/marshmallow-peewee. I hope it would be useful to someone. Thanks